# Simple slopes in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, interpretation

One of my students is trying to do a follow-up simple slopes analysis for a logistic regression. Her study is investigating the moderating effect of body satisfaction on the relationship between number of delinquent friends and alcohol use (0 no, 1 yes).

The effect of delinquent friends on alcohol use at low body satisfaction is:
B = .03, Exp(B) = 1.03.

The effect of delinquent friends on alcohol use at high body satisfaction is:
B = .07, Exp(B) = 1.07.

Both of the above values are from SPSS.

However, she used Jeremy Dawson's graphs to plot the interaction and found this:

[image: Relationship between Number of Delinquent Friends and Alcohol Use]

The SPSS values seem to indicate the effect of delinquent friends on alcohol use is stronger when body satisfaction is high, yet this graph suggests the opposite. Am I misinterpreting the SPSS results?

Comment: Can you post the model summary produced by SPSS in the body of your question? That would make it a lot easier to figure out what is going on! Also, can you clarify that the above graph uses a probability scale on the vertical axis?

Comment: I suspect the graph colour is just wrong. It should be the other way. @IsabellaGhement

Comment: We can't really tell for sure what is going on until we see the model output for ourselves.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement I will edit the original post to add model summaries.